# Get absolute path in Java

Tags: java

I have string:

`String s = "~/abc/d.png"`

How can I get absolute path of this file?

I've tried:

```
File file = new File(s);
String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

But it can't reslove ~ symbol.

Comment: I want this code run on both Windows, Mac or Linux.

Comment: Just remove/replace `~` char. `String s = "/abc/d.png";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java isn't going to know what the `~` means since it's a shell expansion for your home directory. You can do this before handing it off to `File`:

```
s = s.replace("~",System.getProperty("user.home"));
```

Comment: Could you use `File.getCanonicalPath()` for this purpose or is it going to suffer from the same problem?

Comment: @MadProgrammer You can try it, but I doubt it will work. `~` is different than `..` or `.` because it's part of a shell and not a path element.

Comment: Your solution work with only ~ symbol, but maybe path include other specical symbols. Do you have a common solution for other shell path?

Comment: @merrymenvn What other special symbols do you have? The `..` and `.` gets removed by the [`getCanonicalPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath()) method.

Comment: @Jon Lin: I dont't know all special symbols can be included in shell path. I need a solution (library/function) can handle all.

Comment: @merrymenvn If there are any other "special" characters besides the `..` and `.`, then it's part of the filename and do not need to be removed. `~` is the exception, so just replace it with your user.home

Comment: I hope you are true. Thanks to all of you :).

Comment: @merrymenvn It's possible to have the `~` character in a filename. But it also stands for your home directory. Therefore, when you asked to have it removed, the assumption is that you are treating it as the shell expansion for your home directory, and not that there's actually a file called `~` (which is perfectly legal). Obviously, if there's a directory called `~`, then you *don't* want to remove it

Comment: @merrymenvn Additionally, here's a [list of some of the "special" characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words), as you can see, they're mostly OS specific, so some are allowed in some OSes and not in others.